# VIM: Why are replacement tabs different than Insert-mode tabs

Tags: vim

I have a large space-indented file. I replaced the spaces with tabs by way of:

```
:%s/    /<Ctrl-Tab>/g
```

However, when I `set list` I see that the replacement tabs give character `^T` instead of my configured `.___` ( from`set listchars=tab:._,trail:.`). In fact, if I insert a tab in Insert mode then it does show the proper `.___`, so obviously the two characters are different.

How can I insert a "normal" tab with `:s`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "\t" in the expression:

```
:%s/    /\t/g
```

Also, you may want to replace spaces with tabs in the file with `:retab`, by setting, eg:

```
:set ts=8
:set noexpandtab
:retab!
```

Comment: Thank you! One small correction, the last backslash should be a forward slash. But otherwise perfect. Thanks!